# Trying to compile thttpd 2.27 on Mac OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, command-line

I'm trying to compile [thttpd 2.27](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/) on Mac OS X 10.11 from source, but when I issue:

```
./configure
```

It shows:

```
creating cache ./config.cache
checking host system type... configure: error: can not guess host type; you must specify one
```

I try to search online, someone said I should copy some files from `/usr/share/libtool/config*` but the path does not exist in Mac OS X 10.11.

How can I resolve this problem?

p.s. I have Xcode (with Command Line Tools), Homebrew, libtool, automake  and other build tools installed, but I still can't configure & compile this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1. Install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php). Install `thttpd` with this command:

   ```
   sudo port install thttpd
   ```

   I am not using MacPorts and this is untested.
2. Download [config.sub.diff](https://gist.github.com/hamid914/2879f3f8875a7262a793bb9a49ad5fbe) and [config.guess.diff](https://gist.github.com/hamid914/040794804de018808c3f2106abf17749) and put them into `thttpd` source directory. Execute these commands to patch the config files:

   ```
   patch -R < config.sub.diff
   patch -R < config.guess.diff
   ./configure
   make
   ```

   It will compile the source. You may now consider to install compiled binary.

[Original source of diff files is [here](http://marc.info/?l=thttpd&m=102182637423501&w=4).]

Comment: MacPorts tested & working well. Tested on MacPorts 2.3.4 to install thttpd 2.26

Comment: the only problem is, I cannot find the `thttpd.conf` in the system.

Comment: @Raptor did you install with `MacPorts` or by compiling? Maybe the config file is in `/etc/thttpd.conf` or `/opt/local/etc/thttpd.conf`? It depends on the MacPorts prefix. If you are executing the binary file manually, path of the config file can be passed with `-C path/to/thttpd.conf`. You can get a minimum config file from ftp://ftp.slackbuilds.org/13.37/network/thttpd/thttpd.conf